# Kill a process tree using TProcess

Tags: freepascal, lazarus, terminate, kill-process

When I use TProcess to execute a program A, then terminate it, there are processes called by A which are not terminated.

I want to find a way to kill a process tree.

I am finding a solution working on both Windows and Linux.

Comment: What do you want here? It seems like you want us to provide a full working solution for both Windows and Linux. That's a big ask for an SO question. Also, is this Delphi or FPC?

Comment: I am working on Lazarus. You are right, what I am looking for is a working solution for both OS.

Comment: You are on virgin territory. TProcess is a createprocess/execve wrapper. On Windows you probably want job objects. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , it seems that processes created with createprocess  by the child that is assigned to a job are added to the job.

Comment: @MarcovandeVoort : Thanks. It seems difficult for me to learn about it in a short time. I will try it if I don't find any easier solutions.

Comment: On *nix it probably means researching BSD jobcontrol functions. (setpgrp etc)

Comment: This is generally a hard problem. It may also be unsolvable in some cases, for example when a child process "demonizes," it purposefully flags itself as an independent process, so that the OS does not consider it a child of the parent process anymore. My advice: 1) if you control the children source code, make them listen to some kind of termination signal (SIGTERM on Linux) and kill their children for you; 2) otherwise, use some kind of container technology (such as Docker) so that children processes cannot escape the container and you can kill them all with a single command.

Comment: I found this article solve my problem quite completely (on Linux). http://riccomini.name/posts/linux/2012-09-25-kill-subprocesses-linux-bash/

Comment: On Windows... perhaps not the most elegant way, but you can execute "taskkill /PID nnn  /F /T" (where nnn is the PID) to kill the tree off.